# curl to SFTP and list files in directory

Tags: shell, curl, sftp

I am using the below curl command in my shell script to connect to SFTP remote directory.

```
curl -k "sftp://url.test.com/test_folder" --user "username:password"
```

Is there a way to list the files in directory test_folder.

Comment: Why you use `curl` and not `sftp` client?

Comment: Because I need to provide user name and password in shell script and not sure how to use SFTP client to do that. Could you please let me know how to use SFTP client by providing username and password and how to list files and also get and put files to remote directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes: end the URL with a trailing slash, to indicate to curl that it is in fact a directory! Like this:

```
curl -k sftp://url.test.com/test_folder/ --user "username:password"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel. I am trying to run this -> file_list=$(curl -k "sftp://url.test.com:port/test_folder/" --user "username:password") . But getting curl: (2) Failure establishing ssh session. I tried without port number too and still getting the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you now adding a different question as a comment to my answer? That's not the stackoverflow way.

Comment: Apologies. I will post a new question